# Testing at type-level computing in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I'm following [Type-Level Programming in Scala](http://slick.lightbend.com/talks/scalaio2014/Type-Level_Computations.pdf).

I got the below code

```
sealed trait Bool {
  type && [b <: Bool] <: Bool
  type || [b <: Bool] <: Bool
  type IfThenElse[B, T <: B, F <: B] <: B
}

object True extends Bool {
  type && [B <: Bool] = B
  type || [B <: Bool] = True.type
  type IfThenElse[B, T <: B, F <: B] = T
}

object False extends Bool {
  type && [B <: Bool] = False.type
  type || [B <: Bool] = B
  type IfThenElse[B, T <: B, F <: B] = F
}

type True = True.type
type False = False.type
```

When I try to run the test

```
assert((False && False) == False)
```

I got the message

```
Error:(26, 16) value && is not a member of object A$A146.this.False
assert((False && False) == False)
              ^
```

Can anyone tell me please what is wrong in that code?. I'm runing the code as
a *.sc file. (I'm really a new to Scala)

Comment: I requested to delete my answer. Tests from page 14 are for code on page 5. Tests for your code (from page 13) are on page 17. You should carefully go through entire document.

Comment: Thanks @Mmixel for ur help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, you cannot compare types as if they are values. `==` is a run time method, so that would defeat the purpose of doing things at the type level, even if it worked. What you *can* do is look for implicit evidence that `A =:= B`, where `A <: Bool` and `B <: Bool`.

Second, you cannot use infix notation for type members, so `False && False` must be written as `False.&&[False]`. At least in the way you have it defined. An infix type would only work if defined as a type with two parameters, like `type &&[A, B]`

Now we try try out some computations. Here are some that resolve successfully:

```
scala> implicitly[False.&&[False] =:= False]
res9: =:=[False.&&[False],False] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[False.&&[False] =:= False]
res12: =:=[False.&&[False],False] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[False.&&[True] =:= False]
res13: =:=[False.&&[True],False] = <function1>


scala> implicitly[True.&&[False] =:= False]
res15: =:=[True.&&[False],False] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[True.||[False] =:= True]
res17: =:=[True.||[False],True] = <function1>
```

And some that do not:

```
scala> implicitly[False.&&[False] =:= True]
<console>:20: error: Cannot prove that False.&&[False] =:= True.
       implicitly[False.&&[False] =:= True]
                 ^

scala> implicitly[(False && False) =:= True]
<console>:20: error: not found: type &&
       implicitly[(False && False) =:= True]
                         ^

scala> implicitly[True.||[False] =:= False]
<console>:19: error: Cannot prove that True.||[False] =:= False.
       implicitly[True.||[False] =:= False]
                 ^

scala> implicitly[True.&&[True] =:= False]
<console>:20: error: Cannot prove that True.&&[True] =:= False.
       implicitly[True.&&[True] =:= False]
                 ^
```